# Passing ArrayList using intent not working

Tags: android, android-intent, listadapter

I'm having a  List Adapter class which loads service data and  also inflates on custom list.On clicking the image of edit button need to load the data and intent to a preference screen. Data is perfectly filling to the Bundle by replacing the object as Parcelable, but throws marshal value exception.

The adapter code is as follows

```
imageEditIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        InfoHandler infoHandler = new InfoHandler();
        infoList = infoHandler.load(context, pos);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConfigurationActivity.class);
        Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
        dataBundle.putParcelableArrayList("InfoList", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) InfoList);
        System.out.println("b4 pass "+dataBundle.toString());
//      Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
//      fragment.setArguments(dataBundle);
        intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: is it really implementing `Parcelable` ?

Comment: nope... just covering while passing..

Comment: you probably mean `casting`. Your model class has to implement `Parcelable`

Answer (score 0):

you need to implements Parcelable in your class :

```
//InfoList ?
public class MyClass implements Parcelable{

    private String someData;
    private int otherData;

    //you need to add a new constructor from a parcel source
    public MyClass(Parcel source){
        this.someData = source.readString();
        this.otherData = source.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContent(){
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel{Parcel dest , int flags){
         dest.wirteString(this.someData);
         dest.writeInt(this.otherData);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Creator(){
        @Override
        public Object createFromParcel(Parcel source){
            return new Equipment(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] newArray(int size){
            return new Equipment[size];
        }
    };
}
```

For more information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) is the offical doc !